# Forming final array with multiple array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I need to form the final array, its not displaying how i am expecting, here is the code i used.

I need to print the final array in the expected format, I have attached the output how i am looking for in the below section,

```
<?php

 $order_id = 12345;
$array1 = array(
   "firstName" => "Test Fname",
   "lastName" => "Test Lname",
   "address1" => "Test Address",
   "city" => "Test City",
   "country" => "IND",
   "email" => "test@blank.in"
 );

$array2 = array(
   "firstName" => "Test Fname",
   "lastName" => "Test Lname",
   "address1" => "Test Address",
   "city" => "Test City",
   "country" => "IND",
   "email" => "test@blank.in"
);

$result = array("user_id" =>"9999","item_id" =>"cloth","price" =>"500","qty" =>"100");


$itemDetails = array();
 foreach($result as  $res){

   $itemDetails[] = 
       array(
        "User" => array(
        "uservalue" => $res['user_id'],
        "imageId" => $res['item_id']
      ),
        "price" => $res['price'],
        "qty" => $res['qty']
    ); 
 }



$final_array = array(
   "id" => $order_id,
   "billing" => $array1,
   "shipping" => $array2,
   "item"  => $itemDetails
);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($final_array);die;

?>
```

**Output of current Code**

```
Array
(
   [id] => 12345
   [billing] => Array
    (
        [firstName] => Test Fname
        [lastName] => Test Lname
        [address1] => Test Address
        [city] => Test City
        [country] => IND
        [email] => test@blank.in
    )

    [shipping] => Array
    (
        [firstName] => Test Fname
        [lastName] => Test Lname
        [address1] => Test Address
        [city] => Test City
        [country] => IND
        [email] => test@blank.in
    )

   [item] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [uservalue] => 9999
                        [imageId] => cloth
                    )

                [price] => 500
                [qty] => 100
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [uservalue] => 9999
                        [imageId] => cloth
                    )

                [price] => 500
                [qty] => 100
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [uservalue] => 9999
                        [imageId] => cloth
                    )

                [price] => 500
                [qty] => 100
             )

        )

  )
```

**Expected Result should be like below**

```
array
(
  "id" => 12345
   "billing" => array
      (
        [firstName] => Test Fname,
        [lastName] => Test Lname,
        [address1] => Test Address,
        [city] => Test City,
        [country] => IND,
        [email] => test@blank.in
      )

   "shipping" => array
       (
        [firstName] => Test Fname,
        [lastName] => Test Lname,
        [address1] => Test Address,
        [city] => Test City,
        [country] => IND,
        [email] => test@blank.in
      )

  "item" => array
    (
        array
            (
                "User" => Array
                    (
                        "uservalue" => 9999,
                        "imageId" => cloth
                    )

                [price] => 500,
                [qty] => 100
            )

      )
)
```

I am expecting output like above, can we display the final array in that format, can anyone look into it and update me your thoughts. Thanks!!

Comment: How looks your output now?

Comment: you can get above result if `result` array is multidimentional or assign values to `itemDetails` without foreach loop

Comment: @PragneshChauhan, please post me as an answer, If result array has multliple values, that is displaying with keys

Comment: Might be worth reading up on object orientated next, a lot of this could be handled with objects, collections and getters/setters.

Comment: how to you say its a duplicated question, there the requirement is different.@mickmackusa

Answer (score 0):

if you allow only single item in `itemdetails`

```
$itemDetails[] =
    [
    "User"  => [
        "uservalue" => $result['user_id'],
        "imageId"   => $result['item_id'],
    ],
    "price" => $result['price'],
    "qty"   => $result['qty'],
];
```

[Single item demo](https://3v4l.org/oDKcl)

if `itemdetails` allow multiple items

```
$result = [
    ["user_id" =>"9999","item_id" =>"cloth","price" =>"500","qty" =>"100"],
    ["user_id" =>"9999","item_id" =>"cloth","price" =>"400","qty" =>"200"]
];

$itemDetails = array();
 foreach($result as  $res){

   $itemDetails[] = 
       array(
        "User" => array(
        "uservalue" => $res['user_id'],
        "imageId" => $res['item_id']
      ),
        "price" => $res['price'],
        "qty" => $res['qty']
    ); 
 }
```

[Multiple items demo](https://3v4l.org/J3G5t)

Comment: hi @Pragnesh, can we remove keys like , 0 , 1 for item array?

Comment: @Manjunath, Yes if you want an associative array, but make sure it is unique otherwise it will be overwritten

Comment: yes @Pragnesh, that will be unique, only item_id may repeat in each array, but how can we remove 0 , 1 keys from the item array, can we print exactly like in the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

If `$result` has multiple values, this should work.

```
     $result = array(array("user_id" =>"9999","item_id" =>"cloth","price" =>"500","qty" =>"100"),array("user_id" =>"500","item_id" =>"cloth123","price" =>"511","qty" =>"80"));

        $itemDetails = array();
         foreach($result as  $res){

           $itemDetails[] = 
               array(
                "User" => array(
                "uservalue" => $res['user_id'],
                "imageId" => $res['item_id']
              ),
                "price" => $res['price'],
                "qty" => $res['qty']
            ); 
         }

        $final_array = array(
//    "id" => $order_id,
//    "billing" => $array1,
//    "shipping" => $array2,
   "item"  => $itemDetails
);

 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($final_array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [User] => Array
                        (
                            [uservalue] => 9999
                            [imageId] => cloth
                        )

                    [price] => 500
                    [qty] => 100
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [User] => Array
                        (
                            [uservalue] => 500
                            [imageId] => cloth123
                        )

                    [price] => 511
                    [qty] => 80
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: hello @Vaibhavi, can we remove keys i,e 0 , 1 for item array?

Comment: @Manjunath An array data structure or simply an array is a data structure consisting of a collection of elements (values or variables), each identified by at least one array index or key. An array is stored so that the position of each element can be computed from its index tuple by a mathematical formula.

Comment: okay, but I need to send this array to some api, they requested one sample request, we need to send in that format, so in the sample request, keys are not available for item array, so i am worried, how can we remove keys

Comment: @Manjunath You can return response in api by using `json_encode`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you @Vaibhavi, you mean to say send request in json?

Comment: @Manjunath yes, return request response in json.